# Starting selenium always spawns a second window

Tags: selenium

I am not sure if this is the right place for asking this.
Any time I start a selenium test I get two windows. One 
with the command which are right now been performed and 
the second one with the test itself.
My problem is that in this second window I do not have
any of my plugins. I would like to have firebug for 
example.

A second problem is that with the the google toolbar installed, in the first window I always get a dialog asking if I want it or not. Doesn't matter what I click
this will appear again.

How can I avoid these two problems?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Are you able to upgrade to selenium 2 webdriver? With webdriver you don't have multiple windows to worry about anymore.

You can use firebug by providing a firefoxprofile which has the plugin installed.